# Sending coordinates of features of any polygon featureclass to a table

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net

I am trying to store x-coordinates and y-coordinates of a polygon feature in a table. But, i am getting an error message: Item not found in this collection. The code is like this:

```
Do
 pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature  
 If Not (pFeature Is Nothing) Then  
   pPointCollection = pFeature.Shape  
   For lPnt = 0 To (pPointCollection.PointCount - 1)  
     ppolyrow = ptable.CreateRow()  
     ppolyrow.Value(coorxind) = pPointCollection.Point(lPnt).X()  
     ppolyrow.Value(cooryind) = pPointCollection.Point(lPnt).Y()  
     ppolyrow.Store()
```

The error comes in this following line of code:

```
ppolyrow.Value(coorxind) = pPointCollection.Point(lPnt).X()
```

Any help....

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Thanks artwork21, ppolyrow.Value(coorxind) = Double.Parse(ppoint.X)
ppolyrow.Value(cooryind)=Double.Parse(pPoint.Y)